# Is any tools can check my network card health status?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wifi, wireless

My network is not stable. Sometimes slower (ex. speed test result 10 ~ 30 Mbps) than normal, I tried a speed test, is really slower, and page loading takes time.

I tried `Reset TCP/IP (Internet Protocol) and winsock` but it does not work.
Sometimes is normal (200 Mbps+). I see in `Resource Monitor`, no other app is using it.

When **slow**, ping using cmd shows no packet loss.  Using my phone, also results in a normal speed test.

Are there any tools that can check it? Like disk can use HD Tune

Comment: To everyone, I using network adapter (USB) is normal. Just my network card sometimes will **suddenly slow**

Comment: Thanks for the grammar and spelling improvement.

Comment: My problem is solve because of network card voltage problem, change a network card then solved. Question still open because want to find a tool/software to check hardware part specific use on network like hard disk got S.M.A.R.T or bad sector. Network got anywhere can check by using software identifier out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to see the network speed you have, you could try speedtest.net's Windows/macOS app which you can find [here](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/desktop), or even Microsoft's Windows 10 App called "Network Speed Test" which you can find [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/network-speed-test/9wzdncrfhx52?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

Comment: I status out my speed test result. Any no clear from my question?
The speed test sometimes different comparing to my phone or other devices, and my laptop, sometimes only my **PC speed slower**

Comment: @TanBoonJun, results you get from different Speedtests provider always differ from each other, as none of them uses the exact same servers as the others.
Then to your phone, is it connected via cellular or wifi? If it's connected to cellular, it's very likely that your phone connects to a different server on a speedtest than your PC via wifi.
Then, what kind of wifi adapter do you use on your PC? An PCIe one? An USB one? Is the antenna on the back of your PC? If that's the case, it's likely you get a worse connection just alone due to the placement of the antenna.

Comment: I actually have sometimes a similar problem, but you should be able to fix that for the most part by relocating the antenna of your wifi adapter.
If it doesn't help as well, try connecting your PC directly to your router. Do you have the same problem then? If so, then something with the adapter itself or configuration of the adapter is wrong.

Comment: Also, check if your PC does try to fetch updates when the network speed is low. Windows update, at least for me, does slow the network for me down alot.

Comment: Thanks. I concluse something. 
First, Where my pc **slow**, signal strength is full, I borrow the USB adapter from my friends and test, then speed test is normal, same also with my phone. 
All are connect to **same WiFi, same router**, and the **server** for speed test also the same, but only my PC/laptop with **build in netowork card** have slow. 
So I need tools to check the healt of my network card.

Comment: I confirm is no Windows Update, or other app slower my network. Confirm from resource monitor, no sure any hidden apps. And no possible is my network provider problem, I using other devices tested. With *few test*, with *same provider* for different devices for each round, have some different, but only 10 Mbps around. Doesn't have 200 Mbps+ different yet

Comment: Any software suggestion?

Comment: I was about to suggest that this might be a buffer blue problem, and I was about to ask some clarifying questions like when you see the slowness, e.g. in the middle of a long transfer… But then you said that other people connected to the same network do not have this problem. Usually buffer bloat happens between fast networks outside, and your slower LAN. But It is possible if built-in card has a lot of buffering. Have you tried a buffer bloat test such as that from dslreports.com?